# How to resolve Sys.InvalidOperationException: Two components with same id can't be added to the application?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have implemented the jquery data table plugin to the gridview. It works fine on the full page load.
During the partial page load that happens within the ajax update panel,jquery data table functionality such as paging and header sorting works fine for gridview but the jquery data table css is not getting applied,However IE browser throws the error that Sys.InvalidOperationException: Two components with same id ctl00_ctl00_ph1_phGrid_RequestGridView1_RequestSecurityGridView_ctl1_ctl1 can't be added to the application.
I went through the view source but there are no two components with same id found. 
The code i have written is

```
    function pageLoad(sender, args)
     {
      if(args.get_isPartialLoad())
       {
        $(document).ready( function () {
          $('#<%=RequestSecurityGridView.ClientID%>').prepend( $("<thead></thead>").append( $(this).find("tr:first") ) ).dataTable( 
           {
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "iDisplayLength": 8,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
        } );
      } );  
     }
    else
    {
    $(document).ready( function () 
{
          $('#<%=RequestSecurityGridView.ClientID%>').prepend( $("<thead></thead>").append( $(this).find("tr:first") ) ).dataTable( 
           {
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "iDisplayLength": 8,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
        } );
      } );  
}
```

}
Please suggest me how to resolve this. Thanks